# What name to use when citing a font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, typefaces

I have conceptual question regarding the fonts packages available for pdfLaTeX. Which is the most appropriate name to use when citing the typeface? Do you use the name of the LaTeX package, or do you use the name of the typeface on which it is based?

Many books (though not all) specify which typeface they use, usually in a short statement like "Set in Bembo" or "This book is set in Monotype Fournier 10pt" or something else along those lines.

However, many typefaces available on LaTeX are not original, but "clones" of other typefaces (I understand that's a very loaded statement, as most fonts produced are "clones"; but let's stick to LaTeX for now). For example, Tex Gyre Pagella is based on Palladio, which is based on Palatino; fbb is based on Bembo; Nimbus 15 is a clone of Times; etc....

When using one of the above (and others like them), which name is most appropriate to use for the typeface? If I use fbb, can I just say I used "Bembo?" Or would that be wrong?

Comment: I think that is completely off-topic here.

Comment: I agree with Johannes_B and if it's not off-topic it's opinion-based. Personally, I would use the font name you actually used (i.e. Nimbus instead of Times) but I guess that's a matter of preference.

Comment: My opinion: If you really *need/want* to mention the typeface, use the original *or* the clone* or *both*. It doesn't really matter. Who cares?

Comment: Is it of topic? I apologize if it is -- but it is related to LaTeX, so I figured it'd be appropriate to ask it here. Even if it's opinion based, I'm sure there's a "prevalent opinion," or even better, some sort of typographic convention or precedent.... And clearly, I care, that's why I asked.

Comment: For the *prevalent opinion*, go out on the street and ask people. You will notice that they don't care what machine brew the coffee as long as its tasty; nor do they care about typefaces. Show them two different serif fonts and they will probably state, that both are completely the same.

Comment: I wouldn't per se say it is off-topic.  If you use font X which is a clone of Y then saying "I used font Y" is not correct, as you didn't do that. However stating "I used font X" is true, you did used it after all. You didn't state "I sed font X which is totally independent on any other font". If this is important for you why not say "I used font X, which is a clone/variant/foobar of font Y."

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thank you. That sounds sensible and was sort of what I was thinking. Still, it doesn't sound as good to say "I used fbb" vs. "I used Bembo;" but it would be dishonest if you didn't.